# AWS S3 File Sync

Tags: multithreading, amazon-web-services, file, amazon-s3, synchronization

I am trying to do file syncing from local source to a S3 bucket where I am uploading the files to S3 bucket by calculating MD5 checksum and putting it in the metadata for each file. The issue is that while doing so I also checked the files which are already there at destination to avoid duplicate upload. This I do by creating a list of files for upload which doesn't match on name and MD5 both. This operation of fetching the metadata for S3 files and computing MD5 for local files on the fly and then matching them is taking lot of time as I have around 200000 to 500000 files for matching.

Is there any better way to achieve this either by using multithreading or anything else. I have not much idea how to achieve it in multithreading environment as I eventually need one list and multiple threads doing the processing and adding to the same list. Any code sample or help is much appreciated.

This Windows job application is written in C#, using .NET 4.6.1 framework.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/), which has a `aws s3 sync` command that performs very similar to what you describe. However, with several hundreds thousand files, it is going to perform slowly on the matching, too.

Or, you could use [Amazon S3 Inventory - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/storage-inventory.html) to obtain a daily listing of the files in the S3 bucket (including MD5 checksum) and then compare your files against that.

Comment: Do you have any solution within C# and faster than aws cli sync as we need to ensure on the MD5 comparison at our end and doesn't know if aws cli does that under the hood.

Comment: You would be responsible for writing such a solution, or you might be able to find one on GitHub.

Comment: I am in process of writing that solution however need help with the multithreading part where need to access and populate a list in a thread-safe fashion, which I couldn't find online.